# Vertex array objects binding order

Tags: opengl

I know that VAOs store vertex attribute settings and bound buffer objects, but I'm not sure what is the correct binding-unbinding order I should be doing. Is the next order right?

```
glBindVertexArray(vao); //bind vao

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo); //bind vbo
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vec3) * vertices.size(), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_index, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex_index);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo); //bind ebo
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint) * indices.size(), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0); //unbind vao
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); //unbind vbo
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); //unbind ebo
```

At the moment, this is the code I use and it works, but I came to this after many attempts so I want to be sure this is the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` can be unbound right after `glEnableVertexAttribArray/glVertexAttribPointer`, since the binding gets stored by these two functions. Unbinding it afterwards is not noted by the VAO anymore.

Since there always exists just one `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, the VAO stores the last binding state of this buffer type. Thus the index buffer has to be bound up to the moment where the VAO gets unbound.

Your code example is totally valid. You could move the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER unbinding some lines up, but this is not required.

Comment: My code stores one vbo and one ebo per vao. Could it be more efficient? Every mesh whose vertices are uploaded to a vbo has an indices array as well. Note that every vbo uses the same glVertexAttribPointer() settings.

Comment: Another minor item that could be mentioned: Unbinding the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` at the end is redundant. Since that binding is part of the VAO state, it will not be in place anymore after the VAO is unbound.

Comment: How come EBOs behave differently than VBOs? There can only be one VBO bound at a time, just like EBOs.

Comment: There can only one buffer of each type be bound at each time, but you can have multiple VBOs attached to different shader attributes. In contrast, only one index buffer can be attached.